# Customizing Spring Boot dependency versions

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am looking for a way to **customize** Spring Boot **transitive dependency versions**.

Say I want to use a different version of Spring Framework.

Is this possible? If so how - bearing in mind I use Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by specifying the `spring.version` property, assuming that you use the `spring-boot-starter` as a parent.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>your-version-here</spring.version>
</properties>
```

If it is wise is an entirely different question (there is code in Spring Boot that assumes certain things to be available and to make sure that it works you would at least have to use Spring version 4.0.3 I guess.